# su fails: "wget: bad address 'static.zhiqupk.com'" and unable to unlock bootloader

Tags: bootloader

A friend of mine bought a used Samsung Galaxy S6 or at least we thought so, but it looks that it might be a chinese phone. After wiping all data/cache, the phone still had a lot porn/advertisement apps, so we decided to burn original ROM. The only problem is that, we can't get to unlock bootloader.

When I try with `adb oem unlock`, it just hangs by `...`, i.e.

```
$ sudo fastboot devices
mt6572v1_phone  fastboot
$ sudo fastboot oem lock
...
```

So I tried `adb shell` and try to get root access, to see if can do anything from inside:

```
$ sudo adb shell
shell@rtech72_we_72_kk:/ $ su 
wget: bad address 'static.zhiqupk.com'
Unable to chmod /data/.n.b: No such file or directory
        pkg: /data/.n.b
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.runInstall(Pm.java:982)
        at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.run(Pm.java:120)
        at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.main(Pm.java:83)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Killed
```

So this looks for me like a custom ROM with full of spyware/adware/viruses. Any idea how to remove this stuff and get original firmware on it?

Comment: Reading [this article](http://www.fudzilla.com/news/mobile/37396-can-t-afford-a-galaxy-s6-how-about-a-knockoff), I'm afraid you're right your friend bought a fake one. The `mt6572_phone` seems to give a hint of MediaTek 6572 processor, which the original doesn't use... in this case, you might want to refer [rooting MTK-based on Linux PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119068/), but I doubt you can flash S6 ROM, because it's not S6 in the first place. You could try finding a better custom ROM on [MTK Roms](http://www.mtkroms.com/) or XDA forum (be sure to use correct ROM).

Comment: And spyware/malware it definitely is: `zhiqupk.com` belongs to a Chinese tech company, "Hichina Zhicheng Technology Ltd" (just google that, including the quote marks – results raise suspicion; but they also own e.g. `www.mobogenie.com`). Why else would a simple `su` command (w/o params) do a `wget` from there. // So as Andrew already suggested, getting a clean ROM on it is the best (and only) solution.

Comment: @Izzy, I didn't do wget, I did su and su calls wget. But, since this address does exist anymore, wget fails and so su also fails with NullPointerException

Comment: @Sasa Fully understood – saw that in your commands, and that's what I've meant: `su` means "switch user", not "download stuff". If a simple "su" (without any command added to it) does some `wget`, I call that "malware" – not only it's not the *intended* behaviour, but a fully *unrelated* one. That "wget" is a "backpack command", making the "su" binary a Trojan.

Comment: I think I'm taking a neutral side... Googling "zhiqupk" returned `com.zhiqupk.root` as the first result for me, which I believe (but feel *suspicious*) is to root the device on-the-air (probably using exploit). So I kind of under impression that it's "somehow" help user to root the device easily, but with unknown threat. Anyway, better use a safer method to root.

Comment: If you have got a fake "s6", at this point, I'd be more concerned about the hardware actually present. This phone probably only resembles the S6 in looks, so any ROM or firmware written for the S6 won't work on this phone. If you are able to properly identify the phone (someone mentioned that its MTK based), you may be able to root it, and if you are lucky, you might find a custom rom for it on XDA. But honestly, I wouldn't keep my hopes up.