# fastboot commands work. fastboot oem commands hang

Tags: fastboot

My final objective is to do "fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0".  I've done this successfully with a Teclast P80H.  But I'm having trouble with a rino3 pro.  Specifically:

"fastboot devices" shows me "mt6572v1_phone fastboot" and "fastboot --version" shows me "30.0.4-6686687".  "fastboot reboot" works.  "fastboot reboot bootloader" works.

However, "fastboot oem " seems to never return back to my Windows Command Prompt.  It seems hung.  "fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0" hangs.  I must control-C to get out.  "fastboot oem device-info" hangs.  "fastboot oem junkyjunk" hangs.  It seems that ALL/ANY "fastboot oem" command hangs.  ("fastboot eom" with no following command, of course, returns "fastboot: usage: empty oem command.)

Well, maybe it's not strictly oem commands that hang.  "fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability" seems to hang as well.

My device is a rino3 pro.  Android Settings tells me "Hardware: MTK6763" and "Processor: 8 core" and "Android 9.1" if that matters.

Comment: `fastboot oem` commands are (as the command implies) oem/manufacturer and often even device specific.

Comment: your device looks like a scam. it is most likely a fake phone with dummy camera, 512MB of RAM, 4GB of storage and android 4.2.2 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/130278

Comment: Oh, hello @alecxs.  You responded to my other post as well.  That would be funny if it's a fake phone with dummy camera.  My product does not need to use either of those!  That would make the fake actually perfect!  The GUI and USB do operate.  Please see my other message at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230362/fastboot-not-working-with-new-teclast-p80h?noredirect=1#comment302886_230362