# How to use SP Flash Tool to install a new Recovery?

Tags: rom-flashing, flashtool

My friend has a Chinese phone.

I want to install a new Recovery, and I have Lineage OS on my computer, SP Flash Tool, and a recovery image.

How do I use SP Flash Tool? What files do I have to put on the download tab? I have a scatter file. What do I have to do?

Information about the phone:

> Board: MediaTek MT6589 A replic of Moto G 3rd generation

I want to install TWRP recovery, and then install Lineage OS 6.0.

Comment: Where i find the ROM files, like "preloader" "boot" etc etc...

Comment: Did you find the correct recovery for your device? If so, just load the file in Recovery slot (load first the scatter file)

Comment: For safety sake, please let us know where you got this LineageOS - I doubt there is one available for this replica, and the one for the authentic one **can't** be used on the replica either.

Comment: i already installed a recovery, and the ROM is not installed because i got an error, now the /system is formatted, and the phone is freezed on Android screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my notes when I first used it (which was the only time I did):¹

1. Download and unzip the package , Open SPFLASHTOOL EXE and Load the Scatter file (Click Scatter Loading)
2. Uncheck all the boxes
3. Go to / click RECOVERY box from list and load recovery image according to your device/choice (load image from the separate window -->open)
4. Now you can see RECOVERY box is checked and you can see the recovery image location (uncheck all other boxes)
5. Switch off your device
6. Connect your device and Click DOWNLOAD ***button*** on top ***(not the tab)*** , If it ask click "yes"
7. It is done and MTK flashTool will do the rest. If you have problem with flashing tool or drivers install MediaTek USB VCOM drivers.

**Further readings:**

- [How to setup SP_Flash_Tool_Linux](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/tutorial-how-to-setup-spflashtoollinux-t3160802)
- [How to root MTK based mobile devices using a Linux PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/119068/16575)
- [How to use SP Flash Tool to fix MTK devices](http://www.spflashtooldownload.com/2015/11/sp-flash-tool-how-to-unbrick-any.html)
- [How to Root Android and install recovery on any Mediatek device](http://www.cyanogenmods.org/forums/topic/how-to-root-mediatek-chipset-android-phone-install-recovery/)
- [How to use the flash tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4lwL.jpg)
- [flash tool](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Ubuntu_Touch/flash_tool/a/backlinks/)

---

¹ <sub>As the steps speak "Windows jargon" (e.g. "EXE"), I must have copied that from some other place.</sub>

Comment: i already installed the drivers, and the scatter file, and downloaded the recovery img. but always when i try to upload the recovery image, i get a error: Please check the load image file is correct or not? i click on Yes, and nothing happens

Comment: No idea. But AFAIR you don't "upload", but "download". It's a bit confusing first; the tool speaks from the point of view of the *device* – so if you want to flash the device, you *download* stuff to it. So have you been on the correct tab then? Maybe you cross-check with some of the tutorials I've linked?

Comment: @SampaioLeal You got the warning simply because it is not a correct recovery image for MT6589!

Comment: i wrong the word, i have placed the reovery image on the box, sorry i am a brazilian guy, and my english is so bad kkkk lol

Comment: The image size MUST be the same with the one on the scatter file. Open the scatter with a text editor and see how much space the recovery takes (in hex format) - besides, where did you get this scatter file?

Comment: huum, i will see, the scatter i found on google hehe, i think on XDA forum

Comment: @esQmo converting hexadecimal to decimal: 0x2d80000 = 47710208, i have to tranform this value in bits?

Comment: Ok, i use a TWRP Easy recovery install, but i get a new error: The ported recpvery image is too large, and can cause a overlapse. What i have to do? Can you guys help me?